# Displacement but with side faces

Tags: shaders, displacement

I am making a pipe-fouling animation.
I added a shifting(using Mix Shader node) material to the inner faces of the pipe, so it can switch between dirt shader and clean metal shader in animation.

My problem is if I crank up the displacement value of the dirt shader, the face will be lifted and leave a visible gap between the displaced surface and the original surface.

Is there any way I can fill the gap with dirt material using the Displacement node or displacement modifier?
Or do you have any idea how I can achieve this effect?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can duplicate this object and without displacement, may be increase the thickness using solidify and so there will be two objects with same material but one with displacement. That way, the gap will be hard to judge.

Comment: Thank you! What I wanted was to apply displacement at one side of the geometry keeping the other sides unchanged. But I guess that is not possible. What you said here is the only way.